# Understand java regex expressions

Tags: java, regex

```
"(?<=(.))(?!\\1)"
```

Can someone help me break this down?

I understand that `?<=` is looking at all the characters following `(.)` basically any character, but then i get lost on the `(?!\1)` part.

Im very new to regex and while this has helped solve my problem i really want to understand whats going on here.

Thanks!

Comment: @schmosel didn't mean to, just a side-effect of code-formatting. That being said, OP did type 3 backslashes. Maybe it was intentional

Comment: See https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: `?!` means negative lookahead, \\ is a escaped character and `1` matches 1 character

Comment: @hatched No that's not what `\1` means.

Answer (score -1):

- `(.)` matches [any character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) and defines a capturing group.
- `(?<=(.))` is a [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) which matches any position preceded by some character.
- `\1` is a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to the previously captured character.
- `(?!\1)` is a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) which matches a position not followed by the previous character.

In other words, *find a position preceded by some character and not followed by the same character*.

I'm guessing it's used to split a string into groups of repeating characters.